# Get keycode of input.h linux from KeyCode KeyEvent Android

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, keyevent

I need to get they KeyCode corresponding to the structure linux/input.h after a KeyEvent Android.

I'm simulating a KeyBoard in JNI Android.
Here is a part of my code code :

```
void keyBoardPress(int character) {
memset(&ev, 0, sizeof(struct input_event));
ev.type = EV_KEY;
ev.code = character;
ev.value = EV_PRESSED;
write(fd, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event));
dev_uinput_sync(fd);

ev.type = EV_KEY;
ev.code = character;
ev.value = EV_RELEASED;
write(fd, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event));
dev_uinput_sync(fd);
```

}

The value `character` must be a value from the struct linux/input.h
For example if I press 'Q', in Java I get this code value :

```
public static final int KEYCODE_Q               = 45;
```

The value of 'Q' in linux/input.h is :

```
#define KEY_Q 16
```

Is it possible to get a value of linux/input.h of a character from Java Code or to convert Java KeyEvent Code to linux/input.h code ?

Thank you for help !

Answer (score 0):

Seems that mapping from linux code to android has been done using key layout file. You can read more [here](https://wladimir-tm4pda.github.io/porting/keymaps_keyboard_input.html).
I assume that `key 16    Q` is being transformed to `key` + `Q`(`KEYCODE_Q`) and later this event will be handled on higher level.